# Need to listen event from child in setup vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Trying to rewrite the following code to vue 3 composition api.

I need to listen an event from child in component that uses render function.
$on removed in vue 3.
Don't know how to replace $on in setup method.

```
created() {
    this.$on('update-visibility', this.updateElementBounds);
  }
```

Call context

```
  // ...
  methods: {
    updateElementBounds() {
      const {offsetTop, offsetHeight} = this.$el;
      this.elementTop = offsetTop;
      this.elementHeight = offsetHeight;
    },
  },

  created() {
    this.$on('update-visibility', this.updateElementBounds);
  },

  render() {
    const {isPageFocused, isElementFocused} = this;
    return this.$scopedSlots.default({
      isPageFocused,
      isElementFocused,
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The composition API setup function has no access to the dom directly.

Use the [v-on](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#listening-to-events) directive on the child that emits the event in the template. Use the function you want to call when the event is thrown as value.

```
<child v-on:updateVisibility="updateElementBounds" ></child>
```